# Connecting different batteries in parallel - how to calculate the voltage?

Tags: voltage, batteries, circuit-analysis, parallel

I have an exercise: I have two ideal battieries connected parallel:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMbyjG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I calculated a resistance of the whole circut: 0.666 ohm.

But how can I calculate a voltage of the whole circut?

Comment: I like this question, the answer may be possible by replacing them with current sources with parallel load resistors and then adding the currents and calculating the resultant resistance and converting back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, these batteries are not ideal!

Convert both voltage sources (with thier resistor) to the current current source equivalent.
The left one will be a 1A-source with a 1 Ohm resistor in parallel, the right one will be a 1A-soure with a 2 Ohm resistor in parallel.

Then you can add both current values to 2A. With the 0.66 Ohm resistor you calculated, the voltage will be 2A * 0.66 Ohm = 1,33 V.

Sounds pretty much like homework...